# compare images on two different lists

Tags: r

I have two lists of images (list A and list B). List A includes all the images of list B and other new images. How can I know the indices of images in list A that are also in list B?

```
>list A  
apple.jpg  
mango.jpg 
banana.jpg   

>list B  
banana.jpg  
apple.jpg
```

In the example above, what is the code that helps me to know banana.jpg is the first image on list B and apple.jpg is the second image on list B?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sapply` and `which` to find the index:

```
l1 <- list('apple','mango','banana')
l2 <- list('banana','apple')

j <- sapply(l1, function(x) which(l2 == x))
names(j) <- l1

$apple
[1] 2

$mango
integer(0)

$banana
[1] 1
```